# Intermittent blank emails in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My company is starting to get plagued with random intermittent blank emails in Outlook. This is suspiciously similar to the global incident from 4 months ago but NOT that.

The standard setup everyone uses is Office 365 Outlook Windows client pulling IMAP from Gmail. Everyone is up to date, no COM plugins, etc. People are literally just sending emails with vanilla settings through Gmail IMAP and sometimes they are blank in Outlook. There feels like no rhyme or reason - it happens to/from various people and wildly different intervals.

1. Blank email shows up in Outlook - both reading pane and full screen. There is literally NO content. Even if you view source, view in browser, etc, everything is blank.
2. BUT go to Gmail and the content is visible
3. Forward the email from within Gmail and the content is viewable in Outlook in the "new" email with no problems
4. Forward the original blank email from within Outlook to myself and it's just as blank as before in BOTH Outlook and Gmail
5. View the email in Gmail (step 2) and do Show Original. Then do Download Original. You will get a .EML file downloaded. Open that, and it renders in Outlook perfectly visible!!

Whenever this occurs, if the original sender checks their Sent mail folder in Outlook, the original email is blank!! So they will compose an email, hit send, and then both themselves (in Sent folder) and any recipient(s) see only a blank email.

I strongly feel like the issue is content-type/encoding related somehow. I feel like it could be HTML signatures, attachments, or almost anything that is somehow causing problems but I cannot figure it out. It's some kind of weird multipart or other content-type WITHIN the email. Whenever Outlook encounters whatever it is, it is discarding the remaining email content and I thus end up with a blank email. Gmail parses the weird portion (whatever it is) and still continues to render the remaining content. When I forward the email from Gmail (step 3 above), it is resetting or reencoding everything properly and thus that's why Outlook shows it. I don't know how/why the step 5 part works because I'm downloading the original (which should be "unchanged") and then it works in Outlook.

Not sure what else I could offer up. Two identical emails sent the same way could potentially result in one being blank. I think the origin is the original sender's Outlook client but who knows. I'm super out of ideas.

Here is a snippet of one email. It WAS an HTML email but the source shows no multipart section anywhere. It is just plaintext in the raw body of the email BUT the header does have a multipart section. Is the HTML part stripped out somewhere along the way and so there's nothing to display.

Header:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_011F_01D7A494.98702380"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
```

NO multipart in the email body, just plaintext.

```
------=_NextPart_000_011F_01D7A494.98702380
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=20

Hello Team,

=20

Project =E2=80=9C050-FUL NW Library=E2=80=9D needs to be closed out.=20

=20

=20
```

Comment: Could you post an entire example eml file (after changing domain and personal data)?  Please post both the blank and non-blank versions. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: When you post that example eml file be sure you [edit] the question instead of submitting that comment. @harrymc can just follow the question if they want to get notifications on changes to the question.

Comment: @harrymc The EML as downloaded from Gmail is at https://pastebin.com/ypPpC3p5 and from within Outlook Save-As Text is https://pastebin.com/r0edTaAN (completely lacking content) and then Outlook Save-As MSG and then converted to EML https://pastebin.com/q9PHNzeF (still no content)

Comment: The first and last messages are extremely different. My guess is that the message has transited via an intermediary server that didn't understand the advanced security headers from Gmail, or has a bug, so it mangled the message by a hell of a lot. I noticed for example that some blanks and end-of-lines in headers were deleted, so two parameters became one, making the whole message a real mess (if not caused by MSG to EML convert). The next recipient probably nixed the contents because its security data didn't pass. Does your company have two email entry-points into its domain?

Comment: @harrymc Extremely different indeed!  Everyone just uses standard Gmail IMAP settings.  You setup Outlook, add a Gmail account, and all the settings are populated there.  No other email servers involved.  It goes to/from Google.  Since it's IMAP, the copy in Outlook and Gmail should be identical but Outlook can't render "something" properly and when that happens, it discards the entirety of the message content in its local copy.

Comment: I refer mainly to the security headers like ARC that shouldn't have been changed but were still. That's why I believe in a bad intermediate node.

Answer (score 1):

What are the common characteristics of blank emails?

To further confirm whether the issue is only related to the Outlook client, please try to do the same test on other mailbox clients, such as Mail, and check if there're any differences.

If the same is true on mail, considering the impact of some third-party programs on your computer, please try to [perform a clean boot for windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) and check if the issue still occur.

If the issue only related to Outlook client, I noticed that you mentioned that it may be related to encoding. It's suggested to try to change the encoding to UTF-8 for the outgoing messages(File>Options>Advanced>Under International options) to check if there're any differences.

[image]

According to my research, the outlook client itself may be damaged. It is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or uninstall and reinstall Office to check whether the problem still exists.

In addition, according to my research, there is a thread similar to yours which mentions that the impact of DNS leads to problems. Please refer to this [thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/524559/outlook-for-office-365-showing-random-blank-emails.html#:%7E:text=Update%2C%20this%20is%20resolved.%20It%20was%20DNS.), which may be helpful to you.

Comment: I've already tried clean boot, encodings, different email clients, computers, networks, etc.  It is not happening to one person specifically.  The email itself is the culprit and when it arrives in Outlook it is blank.

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned that the issue occurs on different email clients, so the problem may be related to the email itself or the mail server. It is recommended that you contact your administrator to check whether there is any fault on the server.